# Xamarin Form: Custom Extension not found

Tags: xamarin, resources, markup

I created an ImageResourceExtension class in a under Common Assembly name. I checked the name under the Reference in Property window setting. Namespace for this extension is Extension.Common.

The xaml of the working project which using this Common Assembly have a declaration as:

```
xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Extension.Common;assembly:Common"
```

The element was written as :

```
<common:BooleanToObjectConverter x:Key="boolToStyleImage"
                                              x:TypeArguments="Style">
        <common:BooleanToObjectConverter.FalseObject>
          <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{common:ImageResource Common.Images.error.png}" />
          </Style>
        </common:BooleanToObjectConverter.FalseObject>
```

The images was stored in a Common project folder inside Images directory

I named the ImageResource file as ImageResourceExtension.cs and tried ImageResource.cs but none of it work. It just give me an exception saying:

> MarkupExtension not found for common:ImageResource

I have no idea what go wrong. Have follow all the steps for a blog.

The project that I placed those xaml stuff are in a shared project. Don't know will it make any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand good your question !

look at this code:

```
[ContentProperty("Source")]
public class ImageSourceExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    public string Source { get; set; }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Source == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        // Do your translation lookup here, using whatever method you require
        var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource("Project.Images." + Source);

        return imageSource;
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to use an image as you did in your xaml, something like that should work:

```
<Image Source="{extension:ImageSource LogoProject.png}"/>
```

**Note 1:** I only put the name of the image because in the extension, the path is put automatically ;)

**Note 2:**  You have to put the assembly/namespace as I do below:

```
xmlns:extension="clr-namespace:Project.Sources.Extensions;assembly=Project"
```

Also, you're image has to be an EmbeddedResource, do not forget about it. For the path, it's `Project.Path.Image.png` and not assembly as well ;)

I hope I understood your question and I could help you :)

Comment: Nice explanation.. I don't use this way on my feature anymore so can't easily tested but still very useful. Thank you